# object oriented quiz application

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to build a simple quiz app with javascript, and it goes all well, but when it comes to validation something weird happens, it validates my code twice! Once with the correct answer of previous question and another time with the correct one for the current one!
Can anyone please check my code out? Finds where the bug is? Thanks so much

```
(function () {
// Question Function Constructor
const Question = function (question, answers, correct) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
    this.correct = correct;
}

// Questions Prototypes

Question.prototype.displayQuestion = function () {
    // getting html elements
    const qHolder = $('#question').get(0);
    const list = $('#listOfAnswers').get(0);
    // show questions
    $(qHolder).empty();
    $(qHolder).append(this.question);
    // show answers
    this.answers.forEach(answer => {
        let li = ` <li>
                        <label for="${answer}">
                            <input class="option" type="radio" name="answer" value="${answer}" id="${answer}"> ${answer}
                        </label>
                    </li>`;
        $(list).append(li);
    });
}

Question.prototype.validate = function (ans, callback) {
    let score;
    if (ans === this.correct) {
        console.log('**** TRUE ****');
        score = callback(true);
        console.log(`YOURE ANSWERE === ${ans}`);

    } else {
        console.log('---- FALSE ----');
        score = callback(false);
        console.log(`YOURE ANSWERE === ${ans}`);
        console.log(`CORRECT ANSWER IS =====> ${this.correct}`);

    }
    this.displayScore(score);
}

Question.prototype.displayScore = function (score) {
    console.log(`your current score is : ${score}`);
    console.log(`=======================================================`);
}


// instance of Questions

const q1 = new Question('what\'s max\'s name?', [
    'lax',
    'max',
    'wax',
    'pax',
], 1);

const q2 = new Question('2+2?', [
    '4',
    '12',
    '99',
    'none',
], 0);

const q3 = new Question('... jobs?!', [
    'andrew',
    'what?!',
    'why?!',
    'steve',
], 3);

const q4 = new Question('which one is not a programming language?', [
    'javascript',
    'python',
    'apple',
    'c#',
], 2);


// Array of Questions
const Questions = [q1, q2, q3, q4];
// console.log(Questions);

function score() {
    let sc = 0;
    return function (correct) {
        if (correct) {
            sc++;
        }
        return sc;
    }
}

let keepScore = score();

function nextQuestion() {
    // getting the list and emptying the it for new list items
    const list = $('#listOfAnswers');
    $(list).empty();
    // alerting in the console that its a new question
    console.log('A NEW QUESTION');
    //generate a random number
    let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * Questions.length);
    console.log(`random number generated --> ${n}`);
    // display the question
    Questions[n].displayQuestion();
    console.log(`answer to the question ==>${Questions[n].correct}`);

    // validating the answer by click on the submit button
    const submitBtn = $('#submitBtn');
    submitBtn.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let options = $('.option');
        for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            const option = options[i];
            if ($(option).is(':checked')) {
                // console.log(option);
                userAnswerIndex = i;
                // validation
                Questions[n].validate(userAnswerIndex, keepScore);
            }
        }

    })
}

// displaying next question by clicking next
const nextQbtn = document.querySelector('#next');
nextQbtn.addEventListener('click', nextQuestion);

nextQuestion();
})();
```

here is my HTML Markup, thanks again --->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
<title>Quiz App</title>
</head>

<body dir="rtl">

<header>
    <h3>welcome to the quiz app</h3>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div id="card">
        <header>
            <p id="question">
                <!-- Question displays here -->
            </p>
        </header>
        <form id="answers">
            <ol id="listOfAnswers">
                <!-- answers will generate here -->
            </ol>
        </form>
        <button type="submit" id="submitBtn">submit</button>
        <button id="next">next!</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/quiz.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide your html too to debug it?

Comment: sure, i just added the html :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that every time the user presses the next button a new click event handler is added to the submit button.

You would think that since it is the same function that wouldn't happen but you are actually doing it again and again. If the user clicks three times the next button before he submits it will trigger the validation functionality three times and so on...

You can handle this by either removing all other click event handlers every time you add your event. (The simplest one) 
You can do that with the jquery [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) like this

```
submitBtn.off().on('click', function (e) {
```

Where you just unbind all click event handlers before you add your new one. (This way you will always have one click event handler on your submit button). Of course If you want to add other click event handlers to this button (not very often but maybe sometimes you want to do that) you should use it with caution

Another way to go is just not add the click event handler every time the next button is pressed. Just add the event once outside of your NextQuestion function like this (outside from document ready if you want or inside it doesn't matter)

```
$(document).on("click", "#submitBtn", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var options = $('.option');
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var option = options[i];
        if ($(option).is(':checked')) {
            // console.log(option);
            userAnswerIndex = i;
            // validation
            Questions[n].validate(userAnswerIndex, keepScore);
        }
    }
});
```

or

```
    function nextQuestion(){
        // do everything else
    }

    var submitBtn = $('#submitBtn');
    submitBtn.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var options = $('.option');
        for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var option = options[i];
            if ($(option).is(':checked')) {
                // console.log(option);
                userAnswerIndex = i;
                // validation
                Questions[n].validate(userAnswerIndex, keepScore);
            }
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to run the code to be sure since I didn't have the relevant markup but from reading it seems like problem can be in this block of code

```
submitBtn.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let options = $('.option');
        for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            const option = options[i];
            if ($(option).is(':checked')) {
                // console.log(option);
                userAnswerIndex = i;
                // validation
                Questions[n].validate(userAnswerIndex, keepScore);
            }
        }

    })
```

Let's go to third line which is `let options = $('.option');` now again, since I don't have markup I can be wrong but this seems a bit fishy. You are selecting all the elements with class `option` and then iterating over them. In each iteration you check if option is checked, if it is you validate it.

Now in only way in which you can confirm that validate will run only once is when `$('.option')` contains only one selected element. But if you have multiple selects or input elements with class `option` and user has selected multiple of them you might get more than one selected elements. In that case you might see question being validated more than one time

Comment: Same initial thought. :) That's why I asked for the html to run it. Probably that is the case.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see your comment

Comment: No problem I just mentioned it. :)

Comment: thanks for the answer , but to be sure i just added the html mark up :)